# Group frequency data in R

Tags: r, frequency

For chi-squared goodness of fit tests, you would usually want that the expected frequency in each bin is at least 5. If you are given a vector of expected frequencies, how can I do this easily in R?

Let's take an example:

```
set.seed(1000) # Seed for reproducibility
y = rpois(150, 4) # Simulate from Poisson(4)
observed = table(c(y, 1:max(y))) - 1 # Table of observed frequencies
thetahat = mean(y) # Assuming Y ~ Poisson(theta), where theta is unknown, this is an estimate of theta
expected = dpois(as.numeric(names(observed)), thetahat)*150 # Simulate expected frequencies for Poisson(thetahat)
expected[length(expected)] = 150 - sum(expected[1:(length(expected) - 1)]) # Compute final bin as 150*P(Y >= max(y))
```

The result is as follows:

```
rbind(observed, "expected" = round(expected, 3))
             0      1      2      3      4      5      6     7     8     9    10
observed 0.000 18.000 19.000 24.000 33.000 31.000 12.000 7.000 2.000 0.000 3.000
expected 3.098 12.019 23.316 30.156 29.251 22.699 14.679 8.136 3.946 1.701 0.999
```

This last matrix of observed/expected frequencies is what you are given. I want to perform an operation on the above so that bins/cells with expected frequencies < 5 are grouped with adjacent bins/cells so that the resulting expected frequencies are >= 5. In the above example, the above will become

```
              1      2      3      4      5      6     7     8
observed 18.000 19.000 24.000 33.000 31.000 12.000 7.000 5.000
expected 15.117 23.316 30.156 29.251 22.699 14.679 8.136 6.646
```

For typical unimodal distributions (e.g. Poisson, Normal), it's usually just the case that the tails of the distribution would have expected frequencies < 5.

One possible solution would be to write a loop to iterate each column and group adjacent columns if the frequency in a given bin is < 5. I can do this, but is there a more efficient way? When grouping adjacent columns, I would prefer that the outer columns be collapsed inward. e.g. Above,

1. column 0 was grouped with 1,
2. column 10 was grouped with 9 - the frequency was still less than 5, so the resulting column is then grouped with 8

My current code:

```
z = rbind(observed, "expected" = round(expected, 3))
nbins = ncol(z)
while(z[2, nbins] < 5){
  z[, nbins - 1] = z[, nbins - 1] + z[, nbins]
  z = z[, -nbins]
  nbins = nbins - 1
}
nbins = 1
while(z[2, nbins] < 5){
  z[, nbins + 1] = z[, nbins + 1] + z[, nbins]
  z = z[, -nbins]
}
```

Thank you

Comment: how bout you show the code you've tried thus far...

Comment: Much better after the edit. Cheers.